# saving checkbox checked state on navigating from different activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-checkbox

I've a multiselect recyclerview with text and checkbox. I want that if a user selects some checkboxes and then click on "DONE" button, those checkboxes should remain checked even after user navigates to another activity. So that when user comes back to the recyclerview activity page, the checkboxes would still be checked.

```js
//Model

public class FilterModel {

    public static final int TYPE_A = 0;
    public static final int TYPE_B = 1;

    private String mName;
    private int mType;
    private boolean box;
    private String mainId, subId;

    public FilterModel(String mName, int mType, boolean box, String mainId) {
        this.mName = mName;
        this.mType = mType;
        this.box = box;
        this.mainId = mainId;
    }

    public String getmName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public void setmName(String mName) {
        this.mName = mName;
    }

    public int getmType() {
        return mType;
    }

    public void setmType(int mType) {
        this.mType = mType;
    }

    public boolean isBox() {
        return box;
    }

    public void setBox(boolean box) {
        this.box = box;
    }

    public String getMainId() {
        return mainId;
    }

    public void setMainId(String mainId) {
        this.mainId = mainId;
    }

    public String getSubId() {
        return subId;
    }

    public void setSubId(String subId) {
        this.subId = subId;
    }
}
```

```css
//Adapter

public class FilterAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private List<FilterModel> mList;


    public FilterAdapter(List<FilterModel> list) {
        this.mList = list;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view;

        switch (viewType) {
            case FilterModel.TYPE_A:
                view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_one, parent, false);
                return new CatViewHolder(view);
            case FilterModel.TYPE_B:
                view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_two, parent, false);
                return new SubViewHolder(view);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final FilterModel object = mList.get(position);
        if (object != null) {
            switch (object.getmType()) {
                case FilterModel.TYPE_A:
                    ((CatViewHolder) holder).mTitle.setText(object.getmName());
                    ((CatViewHolder) holder).mCheck.setChecked(object.isBox());
                    ((CatViewHolder) holder).mCheck.setTag(mList.get(position));
                    ((CatViewHolder) holder).mCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view;
                            FilterModel model = (FilterModel) cb.getTag();
                            model.setBox(cb.isChecked());
                            object.setBox(cb.isChecked());
                        }
                    });
                    break;
                case FilterModel.TYPE_B:
                    ((SubViewHolder) holder).mTitle.setText(object.getmName());
                    ((SubViewHolder) holder).mCheck.setChecked(object.isBox());
                    ((SubViewHolder) holder).mCheck.setTag(mList.get(position));
                    ((SubViewHolder) holder).mCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view;
                            FilterModel model = (FilterModel) cb.getTag();
                            model.setBox(cb.isChecked());
                            object.setBox(cb.isChecked());
                        }
                    });
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (mList == null)
            return 0;
        return mList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (mList != null) {
            FilterModel object = mList.get(position);
            if (object != null) {
                return object.getmType();
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public static class CatViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView mTitle;
        private CheckBox mCheck;

        public CatViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_one);
            mCheck = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.check1);
        }
    }

    public static class SubViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView mTitle;
        private CheckBox mCheck;

        public SubViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_two);
            mCheck = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.check2);
        }
    }

    public List<FilterModel> getList() {
        return mList;
    }

}
```

```html
//Activity 

public class FilterActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    List<FilterModel> list = new ArrayList<>();
    FilterAdapter adapter;
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_filter);

        fetchDetails();


        adapter = new FilterAdapter(list);

        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(FilterActivity.this, OrientationHelper.VERTICAL, false);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.multipleRowRecyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void fetchDetails() {

        if(list!=null )list.clear();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URLUtils.URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        try {
                            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);

                            if (jObj.getString("Ack").equals("1")) {

                                JSONArray jsonArray = jObj.getJSONArray("parentcategory");
                                for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
                                    JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                    String maincategory = obj.getString("name");
                                    String mainId = obj.getString("id");

                                    list.add(new FilterModel(maincategory, FilterModel.TYPE_A, false, mainId));

                                    JSONArray newArray = new JSONArray(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("subcategory"));
                                    for(int j=0; j<newArray.length(); j++){


                                        String subcategory = newArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("name");
                                        String subId = newArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("id");

                                        list.add(new FilterModel(subcategory, FilterModel.TYPE_B, false, subId));

                                    }


                                }

                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            } else{

                                Toast.makeText(FilterActivity.this, "No Categories available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // JSON error
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "VolleyError" + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("auth", "MY_KEY");
                params.put("action", "categorypostedproduct");
                return params;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_done:
                String data = "";
                List<FilterModel> stList = ((FilterAdapter) adapter).getList();

                for (int i = 0; i < stList.size(); i++) {
                    FilterModel model = stList.get(i);
                    if (model.isBox() == true) {

                        data = data + "\n" + model.getmName().toString();


                    }

                }

                Toast.makeText(FilterActivity.this, "Selected Stuff: \n" + data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                  
          // HERE I WANT TO SAVE THE STTATE FOR ALL CHECKBOXS                                        
                break;
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }


}
```

Comment: Save your arraylist in shared preference and modify it according to your need

Comment: Can you show me with an example how to save? As I need to save the checkbox instance on clicking "DONE" and also need to remove it at later stage

Comment: sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("checkboxState", cb.isChecked()).apply();

Comment: Should this be used inside checkbox clicklistener in Adapter class? @PrashanthDebbadwar

Comment: @sam I suggest you to read about shared preference it'll help you in future its essential thing

Comment: You wanted to save state when submit is clicked right? and one more thing while loading check boxes get state of check box by using the key which you have given while saving and set check box state.

Comment: Yes. I want the selected boxes to remain selected when I go to another activity and then return to this activity. But I need to add the code in activity so that I can remove this setting when required. @PrashanthDebbadwar